# the old version of intel pin tool

Tags: intel-pin

I want to use the dynamic data flow tracking tool libdft, but it requires the old version of intel pin tool. At present, the official downloading page only provides the versions pin-2.14 and pin-3.2.

Can anyone help me download the old version of intel pin tool, such as pin-2.13.

Thanks!

Comment: I think it's too late, but you can try: http://ppa.launchpad.net/md+lp/pintool/ubuntu/pool/main/p/pintool/